# Why is setState is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

For some reason my setState isn't updating...My callback isn't even firing off. I tried defining the function `onSubmit()` as just `onSubmit()` instead of `onSubmit = () =>`. Any ideas? And yes I have verified that my `if (milestoneBtnLabel === "Create")` is executing.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          campus: []
        };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      onSubmit = e => {
        const { milestoneBtnLabel, schoolData } = this.props;
        e.preventDefault();

        if (milestoneBtnLabel === "Create") {
          this.setState(
            {
              campus: this.state.campus.concat(schoolData.schoolData.name)
            },
            () => {
              console.log("here"); <-- Doesn't execute
              this.props.saveChecklistItem({ ...this.state });
            }
          );
        }
        this.props.closeModal();
      };
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the browser console? Also what is schoolData? How does it look like?

Comment: No, if I console.log before setState it even prints.

Comment: I am talking about browser console not the one which you have in setState. Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: Nope, I do not have any errors.

Comment: You are not answering all my questions. Read my comments carefully and answer each one

Comment: `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);` in your constructor is unnecessary because you're using fat arrow syntax in the function definition.

Comment: @Derek that’s correct but that’s not the solution for OP issue

Comment: also try using the function updater syntax instead: `this.setState(prevState => ({campus: [...prevState.campus, schoolData.schoolData.name]}), yourCallback);`

Comment: @hemadriDasari you're correct, the reason the callback never fires is because `Array.concat` does not return a new array, it modifies the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `this.props.closeModal();` removes the component from DOM before `setState()` completes. Try moving that call to `setState` callback.

```
if (milestoneBtnLabel === "Create") {
  this.setState(
    {
      campus: this.state.campus.concat(schoolData.schoolData.name)
    },
    () => {
      console.log("here"); <-- Doesn't execute
      this.props.saveChecklistItem({ ...this.state });
      this.props.closeModal();
    }
  );
else {
  this.props.closeModal();
}
```

Comment: OMG this worked haha, love you brotha. I wouldn't have caught that.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things in your code that needs correction

1. No need for manual binding when the function is declared as arrow function
2. Never recommend mutating an array using concate instead use previous state to push new values into array
3. Also you need to find a better way to close the model like making it wait for 2 seconds and then close the model. Because JavaScript execution will be in parellel so you need to make your dialog wait for previous actions to be completed. You need to think about closing the modal always whenever submit button is triggered but not just when it is only milestoneBtnLabel == "Create"

Change

```
     onSubmit = e => {
    const { milestoneBtnLabel, schoolData } = this.props;
    e.preventDefault();

    if (milestoneBtnLabel === "Create") {
      this.setState(
        {
          campus: this.state.campus.concat(schoolData.schoolData.name)
        },
        () => {
          console.log("here"); <-- Doesn't execute
          this.props.saveChecklistItem({ ...this.state });
        }
      );
     }
    this.props.closeModal();
     }
```

To

```
    onSubmit = e => {
    const { milestoneBtnLabel, schoolData, closeModal, saveChecklistItem} = this.props;
    e.preventDefault();

    if (milestoneBtnLabel === "Create" && schoolData && schoolData.schoolData){
    this.setState( prevState => (
        {
          campus: [...prevState.campus, schoolData.schoolData.name]
        }),
        () => {
          console.log("here"); <-- Doesn't execute
          saveChecklistItem({ ...this.state });
        }
      );
     }
      setTimeout(()=>{
           closeModal();
       }, 2000);
    }
```